# send image from javascript to C#

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, webbrowser-control, internet-explorer-10

I have a web application C#/HTML and I must pass an image from js --> C#.
The command I use is `canvas.toDataURL('image/png')` but the system got in crash.
I use IE10.

Is there any suggest??
Thanks...

[UPDATE]
Scuse me..I have a setTimeout to delay the call.When timer elapsed, the error is

> Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

It seams like a variable visibility. Is it possible?

Comment: Pass an image from file or from canvas? Because the code you posted just works in IE/Chrome/FF.

Comment: I have a canvas and send the content of the canvas --> C#. I have a webBrowser in C# but the call, crash.

Comment: You give us very little information to work with.. Where did it crash? In the browser? In the back-end? Did it work on other browsers?

Comment: I have updated the description. Have any ideas?

Comment: It is a little more clear.. Thanks. It look like your `canvas` variable is not defined properly.

Answer (score 1):

First you need add an input file:

```
<form id="submitfile" action="youraction" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type="file" id="filetoup" name="file" accept="image/*" >
```

then you should use ajax:

```
$('#submitfile').ajaxForm({
complete: function(xhr) {
    alert("Upload complete");   
} 
});
```

Also you can use the way you are using

```
var canvasData = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
ajax.open("POST",'controller/action',false);
ajax.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/upload');
ajax.send(canvasData);
```

Comment: Scuseme I quite confuse... I have a webcam and take a screen: then I would pass the image to C#. Can you explain how?

Comment: Well, take a look this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4912092/using-html5-canvas-javascript-to-take-screenshots let me know if you cant get it.